# Test that production values are still set in sandbox from batch

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have a program object. Each record created from the program object has an external id field that is used for an api integration. If a case's program matches the name of the program record, the program record assigns its external id to a case's external id field via a batch. In a sandbox, it will assign the Test program to any case regardless of the case's program value. The reason for this is the test program's external id points to an external testing environment.

Example test:

```
Program__c p1 = new Program__c();
p1.Name = 'Apple';
p1.External_Id__c = '123';

Program__c p2 = new Program__c();
p2.Name = 'Orange';
p2.External_Id__c = '456';

Program__c p3 = new Program__c();
p3.Name = 'Test';
p3.External_Id__c = '789';

Case c1 = new Case();
c1.Program__c = 'Apple';

Case c2 = new Case();
c2.Program__c = 'Orange';

// batch runs in sandbox

System.assertEquals('789', c1.Exernal__Id__c);
System.assertEquals('789', c2.Exernal__Id__c);
```

What I don't like about this is I'm not testing for how the behavior will be in production. I want my assert to be

```
System.assertEquals('123', c1.Exernal__Id__c);
System.assertEquals('456', c2.Exernal__Id__c);
```

but still have '789' assigned to every external id on the case when the batch runs in the sandbox. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want asert values to be different in production?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that, Whenever your batch class runs, you need to find first if the running instance is a Sandbox or live environment. You can do this By Querying the Organization Table in Salesforce.

```
SELECT ID,IsSandbox FROM Organization
```

if the isSandbox value is true, it means its a sanbox and thus you can add your selective logic, else just use the actual logic.

You can also create an Utility method, that you can call multiple times if needed for your processing

```
public class ApexUtil{

    private static Organization org;

    public static isSandBox(){
        if(org==nulll){
            org = [SELECT ID,IsSandbox FROM Organization][0].IsSandbox;
        }
        return org.IsSandbox;


        }

}
```

src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you have created an instance of an Object and assigned those values. You didn't insert those values.

So, try this and it might solve your issue.

```
List<Program__c> lstProg = new List<Program__c>();
Program__c p1 = new Program__c();
p1.Name = 'Apple';
p1.External_Id__c = '123';
lstProg.add(p1);


Program__c p2 = new Program__c();
p2.Name = 'Orange';
p2.External_Id__c = '456';
lstProg.add(p2);

Program__c p3 = new Program__c();
p3.Name = 'Test';
p3.External_Id__c = '789';
lstProg.add(p3);

insert lstProg;

List<Case> lstCase = new List<Case>();
Case c1 = new Case();
c1.Program__c = 'Apple';
lstCase.add(c1);

Case c2 = new Case();
c2.Program__c = 'Orange';
lstCase.add(c2);

// batch runs in sandbox

System.assertEquals('123', c1.Exernal__Id__c);
System.assertEquals('456', c2.Exernal__Id__c);
```